# Swift Text Field wrap to new line

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitextfield

I'm working on a swift project and have a Text Field. The user can input a string into this field. Currently if the user types too much then the string scrolls horizontally on the one line. How do I build a text field where once the first line is full it adds a line.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

vs.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: You don't. You use a UITextView instead

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`UITextField` is one-line only.

You can replace your `UITextField` with `UITextView` in your storyboard. They are *editable* and *selectable* by default.